# How to efficiently mutate certain num of values in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an initial 2-D array:

```
initial = [
 [0.6711999773979187, 0.1949000060558319],
 [-0.09300000220537186, 0.310699999332428],
 [-0.03889999911189079, 0.2736999988555908],
 [-0.6984000205993652, 0.6407999992370605],
 [-0.43619999289512634, 0.5810999870300293],
 [0.2825999855995178, 0.21310000121593475],
 [0.5551999807357788, -0.18289999663829803],
 [0.3447999954223633, 0.2071000039577484],
 [-0.1995999962091446, -0.5139999985694885],
 [-0.24400000274181366, 0.3154999911785126]]
```

The goal is to multiply some random values inside the array by a random percentage. Lets say only 3 random numbers get replaced by a random multipler, we should get something like this:

```
output = [
 [0.6711999773979187, 0.52],
 [-0.09300000220537186, 0.310699999332428],
 [-0.03889999911189079, 0.2736999988555908],
 [-0.6984000205993652, 0.6407999992370605],
 [-0.43619999289512634, 0.5810999870300293],
 [0.84, 0.21310000121593475],
 [0.5551999807357788, -0.18289999663829803],
 [0.3447999954223633, 0.2071000039577484],
 [-0.1995999962091446, 0.21],
 [-0.24400000274181366, 0.3154999911785126]]
```

I've tried doing this:

```
def mutate(array2d, num_changes):
    for _ in range(num_changes):
        row, col = initial.shape
        rand_row = np.random.randint(row)
        rand_col = np.random.randint(col)
        cell_value = array2d[rand_row][rand_col] 
        array2d[rand_row][rand_col] =  random.uniform(0, 1) * cell_value
    return array2d
```

And that works for 2D arrays but there's chance that the same value is mutated more than once =(

And I don't think that's efficient and it only works on 2D array.

**Is there a way to do such "mutation" for array of any shape and more efficiently?**

There's no restriction of which value the "mutation" can choose from but the number of "mutation" should be kept strict to the user specified number.

Comment: Try something like 1. unravel the array, 2. generate random, unique ID indices with np.random.choice, and 3. multiply indices by np.random.uniform? Finally, you can reshape back. Perhaps a loop is not needed for this.

Comment: @coldspeed no need to reshape if working with a view.

Comment: Besides the typo in your code (`num_changes` vs `changes`), the example you show makes sense but can't correspond to the code: your code always shrinks the number.

Comment: So basically you need a random choice without replacement for any shape array  (not just 1-D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One fairly simple way would be to work with a raveled view of the array. You can generate all your numbers at once that way, and make it easier to guarantee that you won't process the same index twice in one call:

```
def mutate(array_anyd, num_changes):
    raveled = array_anyd.reshape(-1)
    indices = np.random.choice(raveled.size, size=num_changes, replace=False)
    values = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=num_changes)
    raveled[indices] *= values
```

I use `array_anyd.reshape(-1)` in favor of `array_anyd.ravel()` because according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), the former is less likely to make an inadvertent copy.

The is of course still such a possibility. You can add an extra check to write back if you need to. A more efficient way would be to use [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to avoid creating a view to begin with:

```
def mutate(array_anyd, num_changes):
    indices = np.random.choice(array_anyd.size, size=num_changes, replace=False)
    indices = np.unravel_indices(indices, array_anyd.shape)
    values = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=num_changes)
    raveled[indices] *= values
```

There is no need to return anything because the modification is done in-place. Conventionally, such functions do not return anything. See for example `list.sort` vs `sorted`.

Comment: You're right, and I like your answer because ravel() does return a view (+1). However, your result will need to be reshaped back into the original array's dimention.

Comment: @coldspeed, only if you return it. The caller's reference will never change shape.

Comment: `ravel()` or `reshape(-1)`, both will without warning return copies if they must. `ravel` only makes a view if t hat view would be contiguous, `reshape(-1)` can also handle the case where all entries can be addressed quasi-contiguously using a single stride. If, for example, the input was sliced out of a larger ND array there is a good chance that this is not possible and you will get a copy. Which is why you should check and write back if necessary. I do not know what the recommended idiom is but `np.shares_memory` or `A.base is B.base` come to mind.

Comment: Or you could take a view `aa = array_anyd.view()`, try and directly set its shape `aa.shape = -1` and catch the exception that is raised if that is not possible.

Comment: @PaulPanzer. I've come up with a better alternative. The indices will be a bit out of whack if the order is not correct, but they're random to begin with, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using `shuffle` instead of `random_choice`, this would be a different solution. It works on an array of any shape.

```
def mutate(arrayIn, num_changes):
    mult = np.zeros(arrayIn.ravel().shape[0])
    mult[:num_changes] = np.random.uniform(0,1,num_changes)
    np.random.shuffle(mult)
    mult = mult.reshape(arrayIn.shape)
    arrayIn = arrayIn + mult*arrayIn
    return arrayIn
```